# PHP prevent duplicates in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm populating a select field from database. However, many rows have the same value in the same column. How would I prevent duplicate values in a select field?

At the moment, I have this

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE UserID = ?";
$smt = $db->prepare($q);
$smt->execute(array($userid));
while($row = $smt->fetchObject()){
     echo '<option value="'. $row->Column. '">'.$row->Column.'</option>';
}
```

It will echo a new option for every row in the database matching the query. In this case, it could be this.

```
<option value="Value1">Value1</option>
<option value="Value1">Value1</option>
<option value="Value2">Value2</option>
<option value="Value1">Value1</option>
```

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you only want `DISTINCT` Column values?

```
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table WHERE UserID = ?
```

Assuming your code is accurate, you don't need to select all (`*`) from the table as you are only using `Column`m hence using `SELECT DISTINCT Column` is sufficient to bring back deduplicated results and values from Column

Comment: Why? It answers the question.

Comment: @AmalMurali I would disagree, it contains a code fragment which is a possible solution

Comment: @AmalMurali I also disagree with you. It's a correct answer to the question, why would it not be posted as an answer?

Comment: @Shamil: I've removed my downvote, but consider editing your question and mention selecting `*` is not necessary. :)

Comment: @AmalMurali I always select `*`, any reason why I shouldn't?

Comment: @Christian: Perfomance, maintenance, indexing... various issues. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/) thread for more details.

Comment: @Christian You transfer way more data than needed, it's just bad practise.

Comment: @Shamil: And upvotted :)

Comment: @Christian: It's best practice to only select what you need for performance reasons (more data gets transmitted that is needed), but unless you're going for super performance optimization, you're fine selecting *.

Comment: @AmalMurali I just often happen to need almost all of the columns. When I don't select all, I'm probably working with joins.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways.

Use the `GROUP BY` SQL statement in your query:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE UserID = ? GROUP BY Column";
```

or do it in PHP using an array:

```
$columns = array();
while($row = $smt->fetchObject()){
     if (!isset($columns[$row->Column])) {
          echo '<option value="'. $row->Column. '">'.$row->Column.'</option>';
          $columns[$row->Column] = true;
     }
}
```

***Note:** That said, do you **really** need all the columns? Couldn't you just `SELECT Column`? No need to transfer more data than needed.*

Comment: Works, but `DISTINCT` is the thing I'm looking for, as it's meant for this!